# How to get single even or odd number from a array in simplest way?

Tags: javascript, arrays

To get single even or odd number from a array. Example:

`[20, 10, 11, 200, 30]` => will return 11.

`[31, 23, 45, 20, 43]` => will return 20.

I have tried the below function to achieve this requirement:

```js
function getEvenOrOddNum(arr) {
 var checkVal, num, i, len = arr.length;
 
 if (len > 2) {
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   var mod = arr[i] % 2;
   if (checkVal == mod) { break; }
   checkVal = mod;
  }
  
  checkVal =  checkVal == 0 ? 1 : 0; 
  num = arr.filter((val) => val % 2 == checkVal);
  num = num.length < 2 ? num[0] : null;
 }
 
 return num || null;
}


console.log(getEvenOrOddNum([20, 10, 11, 200, 30])) //=> return 11

console.log(getEvenOrOddNum([31, 23, 45, 20, 43])) //=> return 20

console.log(getEvenOrOddNum([20, 10])) //=> return null

console.log(getEvenOrOddNum([20, 10, 11, 23, 200, 30])) //=> return null

console.log(getEvenOrOddNum([31, 23, 45, 20, 43, 50])) //=> return null
```

Comment: what happens if the array contains more than one odd or even number, ex: [1,2,3,4,5]?

Answer (score 0):

You could coount the types and store the last value of each type and check if two values have the same type, then take a `flag` for the wanted type.

Return then the type with the flag and check the count before.

> `l` means the left element and `r` the right one which is the actual item as well. Bothe elements are neede for comparing both types of even/odd.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
>          vv            actual item
> [20, 10, 11, 200, 30]  array
>       l   r            variables
> ```

```js
function getSingle(array) {
    var count = [0, 0],
        values = [],
        flag;

    array.forEach((r, i, { length, [(length + i - 1) % length]: l }) => {
        if (l % 2 === r % 2) flag = 1 - r % 2;
        values[r % 2] = r;
        count[r % 2]++;
    });
    return count[flag] === 1
        ? values[flag]
        : null;
}

console.log(getSingle([20, 10, 11, 200, 30]));     //   11
console.log(getSingle([31, 23, 45, 20, 43]));      //   20
console.log(getSingle([20, 10]));                  // null
console.log(getSingle([20, 10, 11, 23, 200, 30])); // null
console.log(getSingle([31, 23, 45, 20, 43, 50]));  // null
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

This will call the provided function for each array element, and will return the first element which 'match the condition' (the provided function returns `true` for):

```js
const evenArray=[2,4,6,8,9]
const oddArray=[1,2,3,5,7,9]

console.log(evenArray.find(element=> element % 2 === 1)) //9
console.log(oddArray.find(element=> element % 2 === 0)) //2
```

Comment: This does work, so it would be interesting to hear what the three downvotes were for and why?

Comment: dv not me, but i think, op is looking for a single item which is either even or odd and the rest is opposite by taking a single function.